# Page Object Model: How much abstraction is necessary?

Tags: automated-testing, page-objects

So i've been working on a Page Object Model framework for a large web application for our current company. It's the first time i've made my own framework and implemented the page object model. Im using Ruby w/Capybara and Selenium-Webdriver for my language/driver of choice.

Currently i've divided each page (or obvious "section of the site") into a class file. This class file has methods for just about everything (or an API of sorts). The problem i've ran into is that I am literally writing a method for every single thing....and i've came across 2 ways people seem to do this:

Lets pretend for a section/page of the site is a widget creation form, the widget has a name/description and some sort of "type" dropdown. Also a save button to save the widget.

Option A (Which is what i've done so far): Make a method for each element (the save button, called `save_widget`, all the different inputs, etc...)

Option B: Have getter and setter methods for each element, then a larger method which uses these private getter and setter methods.

With Option A my test scripts end up being longer, and honestly not much different than using selenium calls themselves.

Option B would probably call one method (Such as `create_widget` which would pass in multiple items which that method would call all the smaller getter/setter methods). This would make the test script MUCH shorter and more abstracted. However the getter/setter methods would probably take more actual writing for the page objects themselves (but possibly easier to maintain).

Is there a certain style that favors one over the other? The more I think about it the more Option B seems better...but I wonder if in this case abstraction is a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your options listed can work. Though, as you mentioned, option A is only slightly better than not using POM.

Every time I do test automation, it's always been on teams that have no automation, so I'm always creating frameworks from scratch.

In my experience, I favor option B that you have listed. This level of abstraction and encapsulation works best for long term maintenance. And, if there is more than 1 person writing tests, they only need to be concerned with what methods to use and not have to worry about how to use getter/setters. This also allows you to create overloaded methods, when needed, and use the same elements in your getter/setter. Option B allows for more customization and control.

Test specs should be short and contain your data, your asserts, and any class/method calls to implement the test. While your POMs contain your elements and methods on how to use the elements.

Edit:
Note, not all languages support method overloads. An example of overloaded method looks like:

```
public void login () {}
public void login (username, password) {}
```

Same name is used for both methods, the take different parameters, and may have different logic/steps to perform. In this case, maybe the first method is used to login as a guest, where the second supports login credentials.

Comment: "This also allows you to create overloaded methods, when needed, and use the same elements in your getter/setter". Can you describe an example of this?

Comment: @Mercfh I edited my answer with a brief example.

Comment: Ah apparently ruby doesn't support that type of operator overloading unfortunately. Darn.

Answer (score 3):

I might choose option A and do what is needed when it is needed without the extra abstraction.

One additional option is also to move away from a strict page object model.  My reason for doing this is maintainability.  The issue I encounter is the knowledge needed (or gained) for the page breakdown.  You'll often find components that are:

- Universal, e.g. a 'logout' button'
- Repeated on multiple pages, e.g. a attach document to multi-form submission
- Common to a certain workflow over different pages
- Updated via ajax

Because of these issues I create Page Objects as:

- Global.  For simple applications I've even just kept them all in that one category.
- Workflow.  Some elements are repeated thru a workflow or multi-form submission
- Page.  The more classic use for objects specific to that page and no other.

In fact I often start with just global and wait until I start meetings conflicts / collisions before doing the mroe detailed breakouts.  Depends on the situation.

Comment: I typically do have a folder structure for pages/components that are globally used (such as a dashboard page or something like that)