# Representing Complex Objects for Page Object Model?

Tags: automated-testing, page-objects

So this is sort of a follow up question to me previous question: [Page Object Model: How much abstraction is necessary?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/40294/page-object-model-how-much-abstraction-is-necessary)

In an effort to make my test scripts simpler and methods easier (since implementing a very discrete PoM didn't really reduce my test scripts) i've came into the problem of how to handle methods that handle complex forms for example.

With a page object model something like a `Login()`method is pretty easy, it takes a username and password. So even if we have to pass parameters in the test script it's not a big deal.

But for example I have a page that deals with creating a widget for example (That's this particular pages sole purpose). The form is a series of input text fields, dropdowns, etc... (This framework is written in `Ruby` by the way).

How do I go about dealing with this with PoM?

Currently i've made a method for each input (along with the "save" button)...but that doesn't really abstract away anything, and honestly is just as long in the test script as using pure selenium calls.

I could make a method that handles all this (Which makes sense) but the number of parameters I would need to pass would be staggering. OR I could just use default parameters (perhaps using a gem such as `faker` to fill in inputs within the method). Or perhaps have another class (which seems overkill) or fixture to pass into the method.

I've seen some guides that sort of have a default data of `{}` that uses default in the method by merging the defaults into a blank object (if nothing is otherwise passed). Which seems like an ok way of handling it.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: In these scenarios, I have successfully used complex data objects({} Json objects) to pass around as a single parameter between page object methods and defined single big methods to fill in all page UI objects like 'fillOrderDetails' instead of single element handling functions.

Comment: This also make a lot easier to compare all data values between 2 pages(fill order details & confirm order details) as a simple 2 object comparison function.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal this seems like the way to go, as having discrete functions for every input just made the test script super long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A check usually follows the Setup-Act-Check pattern.

In the setup, you put the environment in the minimal state relevant for your check, including your test data.

Let's consider a form that have 3 sections and a few fields on each.

Your test could be some of this sort:

```
FormPage form = FormPage()
FormData data = FormData("some_test_data_file.json")

form.fill(data)

assert.equals(form.section1(), data.section1)
assert.equals(form.section2(), data.section2)
assert.equals(form.section3(), data.section3)
```

Your page object would be also straightforward:

```
FormPage
....
fun fill(FormData data){
    section1.fill(data.section1)
    section2.fill(data.section2)
    section3.fill(data.section3)
}

....

Section1

fun fill(Section1Data data) {
    name.input(data.name)
    name.input(data.age)
    overage.check(data.isOverAge)
    ....
}
```

And the test data object is basically composition:

```
FormData

Section1Data section1
Section2Data section2
...

Section1Data

String name
String age
Boolean isOverAge
....
```

Every single method is follow t[he Clean Code recommendations](https://herbertograca.com/2016/09/03/clean-code-3-functions-by-robert-c-martin-uncle-bob/):

- Should be as small as possible -> One to three lines here
- Should have an explicit intent, both in its name and code -> No loops or ifs here
- Should do one thing only and do it well -> Delegate as much as possible to lower level functions

The *magic* here is in creating almost a mirror of your test data structure and the page object, which allows you to:

1 - Simply create both at test and ask them to deal with each other;

2 - Know almost always the points on the test data and page object you have to change to adapt to a change in the entity the they represent - if you have a new section, just add something to FormPage.fill and a new attribute to FormData | if *age* is not necessary, remove the attribute and change Section1.fill;

3 - Almost no change in the UI will make you have to change the test itself;

With this basic setup, you can come up with optimizing ideas of DefaultFormData, RandomFormData, FormDataSection1 (which takes data from a file for section 1 and randomizes the rest), etc.

Note: Even for the login example, I would argue for creating a LoginData object - *username* and *password* at this moment represent a single entity, and they don't make sense by themselves.